# Why Jquery Ajax send header jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Origin", target) is replaced automatically?

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

All, I use jquery send ajax post request , and in its beforeSend , I add a CORS header as :

jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Origin", target); as below :

```
beforeSend : function(jqXHR) {
                alert(target);
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Origin", target);
                //CORS
                if (headers) {
                    for (var key in headers) {
                        jqXHR.setRequestHeader(key,     headers[key]);
                    }

                }
            },
```

But my target is cross domain host url , such as http://www.google.com , but it always is replaced by local host . Why ?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page in question, or setup a JSFiddle so we can debug?

Comment: Why are you setting the Origin header?  There is no reason to do that.  The browser does it for you.

Comment: @Ray Nicholus , Thanks for your comments , I understand it now base on your comments .